# open any file type from byte[]

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I have an application that allows a user to upload a certificate and attach it to a person within the system.  Currently it is written to only accept .PDF files, but now the client wants the flexibility to upload any type of document into the system.  I have set up the database to hold the byte[] file and the file extension, but I don't know how to make the system smart enough to be this flexible and open any file type I throw at it without hard coding all of the instances.  Any ideas?

EDIT:
Currently I am doing the following.

```
private void createPDF(byte[] file, string Name)
{
    int fileSize = file.Length;

    Response.AppendHeader("content-length", fileSize.ToString());
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    if (!Name.Contains("."))
        Name = Name + ".pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Name);
    Response.BinaryWrite(file);
    //Response.Clear();
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
}
```

However, I need to now be able to send in the extension and have it open.  The document needs to be able to be downloaded by the end user.  I will limit the uploading to not allow any malicious file extensions, figured that was a given.  Thanks guys, this flu bug is kicking my butt and I can't think straight...

Comment: "open any file type I throw at it without hard coding all of the instances." Open in what? A browser downloading the file again or do you mean for some kind of server side processing?

Comment: You don't want to do that :). Uploading EXE and automatically executing it on your/user's system is nice gift to some category of users.

Comment: How are you presently doing this with PDFs?

Comment: What do you mean by hard-coding all of the instances? You can attempt to guess the appropriate handler for the file by simply looking at the extension... If you want something more reliable than just the extension, then you can use magic numbers and inspect the bytes themselves. http://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html

Comment: To follow on what @AlexeiLevenkov said - even if you block EXEs, what if it's an `.ai` file (Adobe Illustrator) and the user doesn't have that on their system?  What if it's a music file or a video?  You should define the *actual* scope of "Any type of document", and then code for that set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `octet-stream` mime-type should work.

```
private void createFILE(byte[] file, string Name)
{
    int fileSize = file.Length;

    Response.AppendHeader("content-length", fileSize.ToString());
    Response.ContentType = "octet-stream";
    if (!Name.Contains("."))
        Name = Name + ".(your_extension)";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Name);
    Response.BinaryWrite(file);
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
}
```